# Installing Microsoft Windows SDK for window7 failed

Tags: visual-studio, sdk

When I try to install [Microsoft SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) but i get an error avoid the installing to complete.does any one has idea about it.I have already tried all solution found by search(except that's of uninstall VS2010).
I got this error in my log:

> 10:03:10 PM Friday, January 30, 2015: [SDKSetup:Error] Config_Products_Install: Windows SDK Setup (failed): Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information. Stack:    at SDKSetup.Product.ConfigureNewProduct(ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)    at SDKSetup.Product.SetupProduct(TaskMode taskMode, ManualResetEvent CancelEvent)       at SDKSetup.ProductCollection.SetupProducts(TaskMode taskMode, DownloadManager downloadManager, ManualResetEvent cancelEvent)       at SDKSetup.ConfigProducts.DoCurrentTask(TaskMode Task)

NB:I have both Visual Studio 2010 & 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience this is because the SDK install is incompatible with updates to the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C++ Redistributable (maybe 2012 as well).  Uninstall the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 + 2012 C++ Redistributable packages for x86 and x64 and then install the SDK.  After the SDK is installed, you can install the Redistributable packages again.

Comment: yes you are right but I need to add a step for it and it is to remove VC++ package from the installation and it works